# How to find the most recent entry in Access before a particular date

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table of FX rate downloaded from Bank Website. The Bank only 
provides FX rates on business days and I want to create a table that captures the FX Rate for every day in January. so for example, the rate for 10th jan should be the same as the rate of 8 Jan since 10th was a weekend and 8th was the most recent business day.

How can i create a query in Access that will create a new table that has 31 rows (1 for each day in January) with the correct FX rate?

Sample of source data table shown below :

```
Date        Currency    rate    
1/01/2016   USD/AUD     0.73    
4/01/2016   USD/AUD     0.72    
5/01/2016   USD/AUD     0.72    
6/01/2016   USD/AUD     0.71    
7/01/2016   USD/AUD     0.70    
8/01/2016   USD/AUD     0.70    
11/01/2016  USD/AUD     0.70
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that in Access with a query alone. You could solve this by creating a table containing all days in January. If you put a second date field in that table which contains the dates of Fridays for Saturdays and Sundays, you can easily join the two tables yielding the result you want (of course without recognition of other bank holidays).

If you want that too, I would recommend something like the following query to fill the second date field in your table with all days:

```
UPDATE Days SET LinkDate = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM [FX Rate] WHERE [FX Rate].Date <= Days.Date);
```

Comment: is there an easy way to create a table with the dates for each date in January ? I intend to do this every month so it would mean that I would need to create a "date"table on  a monthly basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DLookup:

```
SELECT 
    DateAdd("d", [Ten].[N]+10*[Ten_1].[N], #1/1/2016#) AS [Date], 
    DLookUp("rate", "FxTable", "[Date] = (Select Max([Date]) From FxTable Where FxTable.Date <= #" & Format(DateAdd("d", [Ten].[N]+10*[Ten_1].[N], #1/1/2016#), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)") AS DailyRate
FROM 
    Ten, 
    Ten AS Ten_1
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[Ten].[N]+10*[Ten_1].[N],#1/1/2016#) < #2/1/2016#);
```

For the current month:

```
SELECT 
    DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), [Ten].[N] + 10 * [Ten_1].[N] + 1) AS [Date], 
    DLookUp("rate", "FxTable", "[Date] = (Select Max([Date]) From FxTable Where FxTable.Date <= #" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), [Ten].[N] + 10 * [Ten_1].[N] + 1), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)") AS DailyRate
FROM 
    Ten, 
    Ten AS Ten_1
WHERE 
    DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), [Ten].[N] + 10 * [Ten_1].[N] + 1) < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 1, 1);
```

The query Ten is a saved query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM 
    MsysObjects;
```

Comment: would this work dynamically? I intend to do this on a monthly basis so I wouldn't want to hard code the dates?

Comment: thanks very much for that. it works. are you able to just clarify whether the format function is required in all dlookup comparisons? i seem to have issues with other lookups that uses dates as criterias..

Comment: Yes, whenever you need to concatenate a date/time value into an SQL string, you will need a proper string expression of this value, and Format is the only native function that can do this for you - as shown. In a US environment you may get away with more loose code but not in non-US environment (UK, EU, Japan, etc.).